# Missing dependency FreeTypeFontGenerator in fat jar packaged with gradlew

Tags: gradle, jar, libgdx, gradlew, freetype

I am packaging a jar file with

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

when running it with java 1.8 (openjdk)

```
java -jar desktop-1-0.jar
```

a ClassNotFoundException for the FreeTypeFontGenerator class is thrown. The whole Stacktrace is the following

```
    java -jar desktop-1.0.jar
    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
        Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeTypeFontGenerator
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:135)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeTypeFontGenerator
        at com.mygdx.tools.FontLoader.loadFont(FontLoader.java:13)
        at com.mygdx.stages.hud.ClientHud.(ClientHud.java:42)
        at com.mygdx.stages.hud.StartmenuHud.joinButtonClicked(StartmenuHud.java:67)
        at com.mygdx.stages.hud.StartmenuHud.access$100(StartmenuHud.java:16)
        at com.mygdx.stages.hud.StartmenuHud$2.touchDown(StartmenuHud.java:47)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:57)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.notify(Actor.java:188)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.fire(Actor.java:158)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchDown(Stage.java:281)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:357)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:221)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:128)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 12 more
```

I already included the necessary dependencies in the build.gradle file within the root directory of my project for FreeTypeFont as described in the libgdx [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle).

I also refreshed the project dependencies (right-click project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Dependencies)
and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to add

```
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
```

under the desktop section of my build.gradle file.
I tried this out since the import for the [controler](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#controllers-gradle) module looked a bit alike.

I have no idea why this is not documented, but after a refresh of all gradle dependencies (right-click the project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Dependencies) and a rebuild of the project i was able to run the packaged jar without any problems.